# what is the terminology that describe the rate of user view over user order

Tags: terminology

assume I have a e-commerce website, and i need to know how many users that access my website, and how many of them make an order.

the question is, what is the terminology describe the rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two terms that may describe what you're looking for are [**click through rates** and **conversion rates**](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/ctr-vs-conversion-rates).

**Click through rates** typically refer to the percentage of people who click on your ad out of all those shown your ad.

**Conversion rates** typically describes the percentage of website visitors who complete whatever website action you want them to--whether that's purchasing something, filling out a survey, etc.

Comment: +1, I knew only *conversion rate*, but couldn't remember it. Thanks for presenting it.